# permission denied for window type 2038 regardless of the flags and draw permissions

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-windowmanager

I know this question has been frequently asked before but I still get crash reports from many users regardless of targeting their API. So I have a foreground service that I check draw permissions each time before running it. I use the below codes:

```
int flags;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
            } else {
                flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
            }

            myWindowParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    movable_width,
                    movable_height,
                    flags,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_IGNORE_CHEEK_PRESSES | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Error on Firebase

```
Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@1a0fb9e -- permission denied for window type 2038
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:830)
   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
   at com.b.app.mainService.setupWindows(mainService.java:26)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3544)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:200)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you're testing on a Samsung Android 13 phone, I think this might be the problem.

I also contacted Samsung about the issue. And they replied:

We have found SamsungRestrictOverlayProcessor in the log, we are expecting this the reason for preventing the overlay of your application.

Overlay-related permissions are temporarily disabled during calls for applications that have not been installed through an official store (Play store / Galaxy store). This is a security feature meant to prevent voice phishing. If your application is installed through the Play store or Galaxy store or ADB this problem will no longer occur.
During development, it is recommended to only install and test your application either through ADB or Android Studio. You may also try offering closed beta through the Galaxy store for your application for testing instead of distributing APKs of your application through 3rd party sources.

As long as you follow either of these methods for testing and distributing your application through proper stores, the SamsungRestrictOverlayProcessor will no longer restrict the overlay for your application.

I hope this was helpful to you.